# Как понимать слова "эксплуатация зданий и сооружений"

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов

Википедия: [Эксплуатация зданий и сооружений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) — комплекс работ по содержанию, обслуживанию и ремонту здания (сооружения).

ТОЛКОВЫЙ СЛОВАРЬ "ПРОФЕССИИ/КВАЛИФИКАЦИИ И СПЕЦИАЛЬНОСТИ": 
[ОБСЛУЖИВАНИЕ И ЭКСПЛУАТАЦИЯ ЖИЛЫХ ДОМОВ](http://kudapostupat.by/speciality/id/576). Специальность обеспечивает получение квалификации «Специалист по комплексному  обслуживанию и эксплуатации жилых домов».

Исходя из этого обслуживающие компании считают, что они,а не жильцы занимаются эксплуатацией жилого дома.

В каком словаре отражено такое понимание слова *эксплуатация*? Вот "Большой толковый словарь" говорит:

[ЭКСПЛУАТИРОВАТЬ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20) — Использовать по назначению орудия и средства производства, механизмы и т.п., а также сооружения, здания, территории и т.п. Э. оборудование. Э. мост в течение столетия. Э. горы для научных исследований. Э. пляжи как зону отдыха. <Эксплуатироваться, -руется; страд. Эксплуатирование, -я; ср. Э. трудящихся. Э. здания. Э. автобуса.

То есть жильцы эксплуатируют (используют) свое жилье, а компании его только ремонтируют. Или я не прав?

Answer (score 1):

Приведённое определение - неполное: в процесс эксплуатации входит не только пользование, но и работы по поддержанию жилья в исправном состоянии, причём в этот процесс вовлечены и сами жильцы - в их интересах вовремя привлечь специалистов в сложных случаях, а в квартире они поддерживают порядок, иногда сами ремонт делают. Эта сторона эксплуатации (элемент длительного поддержания в должном состоянии), по-видимому, лучше известна в технике, чем в филологии. Работа со станками, телекамерами на телецентрах и пр. профессиональными полезными объектами разделена на области проектирования, изготовления и эксплуатации (элемент потребления снижен по ср. с жильём). Разделение труда таково, что часть специалистов занимается исключительно эксплуатацией технических средств (профессиональное применение и, грубо говоря, периодический ремонт этого же - таково содержание эксплуатации в технике), не создавая ничего нового.

Comment: Есть ли такое определение в каком-либо академическом словаре?

Comment: Пока нашёл в ГОСТ "ЭКСПЛУАТАЦИЯ ТЕХНИКИ. Термины и определения": Эксплуатация - Стадия жизненного цикла изделия, на которой реализуется, поддерживается и восстанавливается его качество.

Comment: Можно ли оторвать "поддерживается и восстанавливается" от  "реализуется" и считать это эксплуатацией (ведь "специалист по комплексному обслуживанию и эксплуатации жилых домов" не участвует в "реализации")?

Comment: Можно. Тогда это будет называться "Технической эксплуатацией" (оттуда же): "Часть эксплуатации, включающая транспортирование, хранение, техническое обслуживание и ремонт изделия".